# docker multi-platform images in artifactory

Tags: docker, artifactory, buildx

I'm wondering if there is a possibility to have a cleaner docker repo when pushing multi-platform images with `docker buildx`.
We recently switched from standard `docker build` to `docker buildx` since we need to build multi-platform images for `linux/amd64` and `linux/arm64`.
When a new image is pushed to our internal artifactory docker repo there is a new directory created with the respective tag (e.g. `pr_123`) and inside there is a `list.manifest.json` file. The actual images are in separate folders with the schema `sha256:1234abcd...`.

Before with `docker build` (single platform builds) we had everything in the tag folder (e.g. `pr_123`).
Is there a possibility to configure `docker buildx` in a way to have a cleaner structure?
The `sha256:...` names are not very intuitive and are polluting the artifactory quite a lot...